# Bring a list of users back and forth after skipping certain iterations

Tags: python, for-loop

I am doing some analysis in which I am applying a certain filter to remove certain users who have seen a particular content(tactic).

The original dataframe looks like:

```
user content response

100   esample  0
101   esample  1
.................
106   esample  0
```

Now this dataframe is simulated in various iterations. So in every iteration we have different dataset with same columns. Now at every iteration I want to filter  the users who have seen 'esample' and bring them after two subsequent iterations. For instance users in tactic1_list(those who have seen esample) should not be considered for analysis in 3rd and 4th iteration. They are brought again in analysis in 5th iteration.

```
for i in range(2,10): 
#Apply a filter on original dataframe(df) and create a list at each iteration
#segregate those users who have seen a Esample content
tactic1_list=df.loc[(df.tactic=='Esample') & (df.response > 0)]['muid'].tolist()
# exclude these users from original dataframe
tactic1_sample_muids= list(set(df.muid).difference(tactic1_list))
###Further analysis
```

Now I want  to code in such a way such that the users in tactic1_list should be used again after subsequent 2 iterations. I was thinking to use continue, but not sure how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is about how to use continue in your case to achieve your goal

```
for i in range(2,10):
    if i in [3,4]: # if 3 and 4 or 3rd and 4th iteration number
        continue
    # otherwise process user
```

Comment: Thanks!!. But I have to include this check at every iteration, not just only i=2.  for i=3 it should be [4,5] and so on. So it has to be automated in some sense.

Comment: What is the condition or logic for that check?

Comment: Please see the question again.  If certain users have seen a tactic, then they are excluded in that iteration and subsequent two iterations. The third and fourth iteration explanation is just one example(that's why used for instance)

Comment: Can you explain bit more in your question. How are you processing user ? update your code. it is not enough to get insight

Comment: Edited..hope it helps now!!